# Unusual DHCP behavior on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, dhcp

Our work network router does DHCP in the 192.168.10.# range with gateway=192.168.10.1, behind a centurylink/qwest modem at 192.168.0.1.  Addresses are allocated starting with 100, so 192.168.10.100, 10.101, etc.

One computer on the network recently started showing an IP address of 10.0.1.13 with a gateway of 10.0.1.1 and can still see the internet fine.  A tracert of google shows what looks like another router in front of our normal router - here's an approximation:

```
tracert 8.8.8.8
10.0.1.1
192.168.10.1
192.168.0.1
qwest.net stuff
other stuff
eventually to 8.8.8.8, google
```

I can't figure out what is going on other than some weird virus that has installed a virtual network layer of some sort.  The network control panel still shows just two network ports and they are configured for normal DHCP allocation.

I ran netstat /b and don't see anything unusual, and have run a scan with MS Essentials that turned up clean.  We have done multiple power cycles, disabling the network adaptors, tried both network ports and get similar results (10.0.1.13 or 10.0.1.9)

Any ideas of what to try next?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/704637/getting-strange-ip-address-from-router?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like someone plugged in a router in the network with a DHCP server which gives out the 10.0.1.1 range, and the WAN port is connected to the LAN in segment 192.168.10.x

Find the 2nd router and disable DHCP or completely remove the device from the network.

The reason for this conclusion is the fact that the traceroute goes through both network. Any device with just DHCP would cause internet to stop working. Because it is a router with separate network, find the device by following the physical wire from that pc to where it leads.

Comment: I already traced the wire into an unmanaged cisco switch, and bypassed the switch directly into the 192.168.10.1 router, I'm still getting this which is what leads me to believe it is something INSIDE the computer (cue spooky music...the call is coming from inside the house!)

Comment: I'd say thats not possible. If you set a hard ip address on your computer it won't ping to the normal system. The only thing that could be it, is if the pc runs a VM, and you've seen the VM's OS rather than the real os. But a normal VM would not use 10.0.1.1. range. Is the PC connected to both lan and WiFi perhaps? Maybe this is through an access point.

Comment: We've now found two PCs on the network in the 10.0.1.# range, and neither have wifi.  We use the DSL modem as a wifi hotspot but it is outside our main router, so only hard wired devices should be inside the network

Comment: If someone plugged their own wifi router inside our network, could it start assigning IP addresses to other computers on the network, or would it have to be directly between the computer and the router?

Comment: Was able to ping /t 10.0.1.1 (continuously) and then started unplugging devices from the unmanaged switch.  Eventually found the port with the new DHCP gateway -- an Apple airport router inside the network to give better wifi signal near that area.  Thanks for the help!