# I was getting strange IP Adress from my (2nd) router ad figure it out it was I change the ethernet port. Why I was getting strange IP?

Tags: networking, router, ip, ethernet, dd-wrt

I have two Routers, the 2nd a tp-link with dd-wrt. I configure it with the same SSID and other options to have one big wifi network. 
It worked well. But from one moment to another I was not getting internet.

At first I though I was being hacked. Then I found https://superuser.com/a/1145468/273358 
And it turn out my ethernet cable was connected on a different port. Switched it, solve it.

EDIT: the strange IPs were:
It was usually 192.168.100.1 for the 2nd router and 192.168.100.4 for my laptop.

But then I got

```
inet 169.254.83.125 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
```

And I made a ping:

```
ping 224.0.0.251
PING 224.0.0.251 (224.0.0.251): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 169.254.83.125: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from 169.254.193.60: icmp_seq=0 ttl=255 time=92.558 ms
```

And arp:

```
$ arp -a
? (169.254.83.125) at x:x:xx:xx:xx:e9 on en7 permanent [ethernet]
? (169.254.193.60) at x:xx:xx:xx:6f on en7 [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at x:xx:xx:xx:xx:fb on en7 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

But I want to know what happened.

Comment: What _was_ the “strange IP address”?

Comment: I will answer making and edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happened was that you were plugged into the wrong port and there was no DHCP server available on the network, and so your device used a self-assigned link-local IP address as defined in [RFC3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927).